# Including 'key' & 'value' properties to json response

Tags: php, mysql, json, d3.js

Query DB table, fetch array, and write to json file.

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM omharddown ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$result2 = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql2);

$json_response = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $row_array 'key:'['ING_SW_CB'] = $row 'value:'['ING_SW_CB'];
    $row_array 'key:'['SB_SW_CB'] = $row 'value:'['SB_SW_CB'];
    $row_array 'key:'['NG3_SW_CB'] = $row 'value:'['NG3_SW_CB'];
    $row_array 'key:'['Mould_Close'] = $row 'value:'['Mould_Close'];
    $row_array 'key:'['Leak_Test'] = $row 'value:'['Leak_Test'];
    $row_array 'key:'['ML_Load'] = $row 'value:'['ML_Load'];
    $row_array 'key:'['Pre_Heat'] = $row 'value:'['Pre_Heat'];
    $row_array 'key:'['Dispense'] = $row 'value:'['Dispense'];
    $row_array 'key:'['A310'] = $row 'value:'['A310'];
    $row_array 'key:'['Gelation'] = $row 'value:'['Gelation'];
    $row_array 'key:'['Platen'] = $row 'value:'['Platen'];
    $row_array 'key:'['Mainline_Unload'] = $row 'value:'['Mainline_Unload'];
    $row_array 'key:'['De_mould'] = $row 'value:'['De_mould'];
    $row_array 'key:'['Clean_Up'] = $row 'value:'['Clean_Up'];
    $row_array 'key:'['Soda_Blast'] = $row 'value:'['Soda_Blast'];
    $row_array 'key:'['Miscellaneous'] = $row 'value:'['Miscellaneous'];

    //push the values in the array
    array_push($json_response,$row_array);
}
    //echo json_encode($json_response);
    $json_data = json_encode($json_response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    file_put_contents('your_json_file.json', $json_data);
```

The output in the json file is such:

```
[[{"ING_SW_CB":"5","SB_SW_CB":"3",.........}]]
```

What I am looking for is:

```
[[{"key":"ING_SW_CB", "value":"5", "key":"SB_SW_CB", "value":3,....}]]
```

Does anyone out there have a solution?

I have created a D3 chart which uses external json data.
the chart accepts the y values but I need to fugure out how to use the category names on the x axis.
Code to populate chart.

barData = [];

```
    d3.json("your_json_file.json", function (data) {

     for (key in data) {
         barData.push(data[key].ING_SW_CB)
         barData.push(data[key].SB_SW_CB)
         barData.push(data[key].NG3_SW_CB)
         barData.push(data[key].Mould_Close)
         barData.push(data[key].Leak_Test)
         barData.push(data[key].ML_Load)
         barData.push(data[key].Pre_Heat)
         barData.push(data[key].Dispense)
         barData.push(data[key].A310)
         barData.push(data[key].Gelation)
         barData.push(data[key].Platen)
         barData.push(data[key].Mainline_Unload)
         barData.push(data[key].De_mould)
         barData.push(data[key].Clean_Up)
         barData.push(data[key].Soda_Blast)
         barData.push(data[key].Miscellaneous)
         // add more .push if needed
     }
```

Comment: your desired format is invalid as you will have multiple `key` and `value` keys in the same object, which is not possible. It needs to be in the format you currently have OR `[[{"key":"ING_SW_CB", "value":"5"}, {"key":"SB_SW_CB", "value":3,....}]]`

Comment: Why do you want JSON in that format? You're effectively removing the association between the keys and their values, and counting on the order of different key/value pairs to reestablish it.

Comment: I have created a chart in D3 and need the data from an external json file to populate. The best example I've seen uses a similar format.

Comment: You probably want it in the format suggested by @Sean, which retains the association by separating the key/value pairs into objects.

Comment: Thank you both for your replies. How would I write to file as [[{"key":"ING_SW_CB", "value":"5"}, {"key":"SB_SW_CB", "value":3,....}]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you data looks like this:

```
var current_data = [{
    "ING_SW_CB": "5",
    "SB_SW_CB": "3",
    "NG3_SW_CB": "2",
    "Mould_Close": "8",
    "Leak_Test": "6",
    "ML_Load": "2",
    "Pre_Heat": "1"
}]
```

... you can use [`d3.entries`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_entries) to convert it to the format you mention in your comment. Try:

```
var formatted_data = d3.entries(current_data[0]);
```

This will give you:

[image: showing the correct data format in console]

Comment: Would I use d3.entries within the function that calls the external json file?